# Is this aquatic plant duckweed or something else?

Tags: species-identification, botany, limnology

[image] 
This plant has been growing in my pond for quite a time now. It multiplies in large numbers rapidly. 
 Some told me it is duckweed or is it something else?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add additional information as specified in the "species-identification" tag (hover over or click the tag to see details). In particular, measurements of the leaf diameter might be very helpful. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

That looks very much like a [duckweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemnoideae).

The multiple roots rule out most genera within this group and so this is probably a [*Spirodela*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirodela).

The apparently relatively large size and red undersides are consistent with this being [*Spirodela polyrhiza*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirodela_polyrhiza).

[image: Spirodela polyrhiza by Christian Fischer (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Fice)]

Picture by Christian Fischer available under [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

Answer (score -3):

Not duck weed. It is Salvinia species very easy to grow ( invasive). I believe it is illegal to introduce in some US states. Koi /carp will eat duck weed.There are a few similar species of salvinia , unfortunately references will give the same name for different plants. My book ( Aquarium Plants ; Barry Jones, Tetra press) calls it auriculata which I believe is wrong. Auriculata is also called giant salvinia and looks different ( see comments @ tyersome ). I have grown Auriculata but not the salvinia that you have.

Comment: This is not correct — [*Salvinia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvinia) species look completely different, for example they have hairs on the leaf surface and their "roots" look completely different — see for example here: https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/48444.

Comment: I have edited to what I believe is correct.